# Get specific MySQL data from array within value?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to get a specific value out of a MySql database.

I have:

```
SELECT option_value 
FROM wp_options 
WHERE option_name = 'DevloungePluginSeriesAdminOptions'
```

Which outputs:

```
a:4:{s:11:"add_content";s:4:"true";s:7:"content";s:45:"155000009-9a5sg2t42q2k0159ko8hkdo85hjlu69j";s:11:"show_header";s:4:"true";s:14:"comment_author";s:4:"true";}
```

I think this is some sort of array. I don't know how handle it. I only want the `155000009-9a5sg2t42q2k0159ko8hkdo85hjlu69j` part of the string.

How can I get just `155000009-9a5sg2t42q2k0159ko8hkdo85hjlu69j`?

Comment: Unsewialize that string and grab it from the array. Then fix your software not to store data in serialized strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data is in serialized format. You need to unserialize it before extracting the array value.

Suppose result object is $result, then following code will work:

```
$option_value = unserialize( $result->option_value );
$output = $option_value['content'];
```

Answer (score 0):

put the value in a variable and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php):

```
$val = unserialize( $val );
```

You'll get a PHP array as a result, inspect it with

```
print_r( $val );
```